# Вью для сообщения

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, дизайн, ios8

Необходимо кодом нарисовать такое вью, можете подсказать как это сделать ??

(добавить прямоугольным вью хвостики)

[image: Вью для сообщения в чате]

Comment: можно конкретнее, вам надо месседжер сделать, или эти странные линии наложить или попиксельно нарисовать эту конкретную картинку?

Comment: Прошу прощения, необходимо вью сообщений добавить хвостики.

Comment: нарисовать их в фотошопе и добавлять ко всем пузырям

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие *view* не надо рисовать кодом.
Лучше использовать 2 изображения, одно для пузыря тянущееся, второе для хвостиков. 
При этом фон каждого представления для отображения сообщений будет состоять из двух UIImageView: одно для пузыря и одно для хвостика. 
Примерно вот так они будут расположены:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще можно обойтись одним изображением (главное правильно расставить *slices*), но часто двумя удобнее.

Comment: Огромное Спасибо !